# asp.net sql how to send instruction to users to be read or unread?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Hi i want to send instructions to all users by asp.net when the user logging then he read it after that disappear from his page.
later on i can know who reads and who does not.
what should i do a table and query or there is a way?

Comment: Have a checkbox, and ask to click that if they read it. otherwise do not let them proceed

Comment: if you want to ensure that this never appears for them again, then you should probably store it as a bit flag, defaulted to off at the user level (however that's defined in your database) and flip it to on after the user has viewed and confirmed it...use this same flag to determine if the message should be displayed or not, if it's flipped on, then bypass it, else display it. can't really provide much more detail without knowing more about how you have your environment set up.

Comment: While the other comments give you a general direction, thing you might want to expand your question a little as it's really a little unclear as to exactly what you are asking and what technology you're working with apart from asp.net.  You could also look a breaking this into some pretty well defined sections.  For example pop up your instructions, handling the acknowledgment, storing the acknowledgement and reporting on the users etc.  You haven't even explained how are you authenticating users if at all, or are you looking to store this in cookies.